# Python RESTful API calls throw exceptions - is something wrong with my Python? (Debian 12 + Python3.11)

Tags: python-3.x, rest

I am trying to install the **Western Digital Resource Manager** (WDRM).
I'm using the Linux version, and I'm using Debian 12.

The WDRM application launches and works fine, except when it comes to running the tasks that are Python related.

In the REST interface logs, I see exceptions being thrown when Python is used to leverage certain WD chassis management tools.

Here is an example of the log showing proper execution of many tasks, but falling apart when a Python action is taken:

```
2023-10-10 21:45:22,928|INFO | 10.168.101.99 - - [10/Oct/2023:21:45:22 -0400] "POST /api/login HTTP/1.1" 201 227 "<url-deleted-for-posting>10.168.101.129/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-10-10 21:45:22,949|INFO | 10.168.101.99 - - [10/Oct/2023:21:45:22 -0400] "GET /storage/megaraid/controller/list HTTP/1.1" 200 3 "<url-deleted-for-posting>10.168.101.129/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-10-10 21:45:22,968|INFO | 10.168.101.99 - - [10/Oct/2023:21:45:22 -0400] "GET /dashboard/sysinfo HTTP/1.1" 200 766 "<url-deleted-for-posting>10.168.101.129/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-10-10 21:45:23,037|INFO | 10.168.101.99 - - [10/Oct/2023:21:45:23 -0400] "GET /storage/megaraid/controller/list?serial=USWSJ01219EZ0023 HTTP/1.1" 200 3 "<url-deleted-for-posting>10.168.101.129/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-10-10 21:45:23,044|INFO | 10.168.101.99 - - [10/Oct/2023:21:45:23 -0400] "GET /dashboard/events?serial=USWSJ01219EZ0023 HTTP/1.1" 200 39853 "<url-deleted-for-posting>10.168.101.129/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-10-10 21:45:23,050|INFO | 10.168.101.99 - - [10/Oct/2023:21:45:23 -0400] "GET /dashboard/sysinfo?serial=USWSJ01219EZ0023 HTTP/1.1" 200 744 "<url-deleted-for-posting>10.168.101.129/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-10-10 21:45:23,051|INFO | 10.168.101.99 - - [10/Oct/2023:21:45:23 -0400] "GET /dashboard/graph_data?serial=USWSJ01219EZ0023 HTTP/1.1" 200 237 "<url-deleted-for-posting>10.168.101.129/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-10-10 21:45:23,051|INFO | 10.168.101.99 - - [10/Oct/2023:21:45:23 -0400] "GET /dashboard/sysinfo HTTP/1.1" 200 766 "<url-deleted-for-posting>10.168.101.129/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-10-10 21:45:23,052|INFO | token received eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJwdWJsaWNfaWQiOiIxNTgyNGI4Ni00NTQyLTQxODgtOWVjMi1mYWI2ZmVjYTg1ZTEiLCJleHAiOjE2OTY5OTA1MjJ9.V_p9wX-rxULPvwIsuh4CFX-dosunJMiKHa5gCU9XGCg
2023-10-10 21:45:23,053|INFO | 10.168.101.99 - - [10/Oct/2023:21:45:23 -0400] "GET /storage/megaraid/controller/list?serial=USWSJ01219EZ0023 HTTP/1.1" 200 3 "<url-deleted-for-posting>10.168.101.129/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-10-10 21:45:23,053|INFO | read session table
2023-10-10 21:45:23,054|INFO | {'_id': ObjectId('6525fe326b44e9c76851f353'), 'record_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 11, 1, 45, 22, 927000), 'user_name': 'urmadmin', 'token': 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJwdWJsaWNfaWQiOiIxNTgyNGI4Ni00NTQyLTQxODgtOWVjMi1mYWI2ZmVjYTg1ZTEiLCJleHAiOjE2OTY5OTA1MjJ9.V_p9wX-rxULPvwIsuh4CFX-dosunJMiKHa5gCU9XGCg'}
2023-10-10 21:45:23,054|INFO | session found : [{'record_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 11, 1, 45, 22, 927000), 'user_name': 'urmadmin', 'token': 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJwdWJsaWNfaWQiOiIxNTgyNGI4Ni00NTQyLTQxODgtOWVjMi1mYWI2ZmVjYTg1ZTEiLCJleHAiOjE2OTY5OTA1MjJ9.V_p9wX-rxULPvwIsuh4CFX-dosunJMiKHa5gCU9XGCg'}]
2023-10-10 21:45:23,054|INFO | update session : {'record_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 11, 1, 45, 23, 54262), 'user_name': 'urmadmin', 'token': 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJwdWJsaWNfaWQiOiIxNTgyNGI4Ni00NTQyLTQxODgtOWVjMi1mYWI2ZmVjYTg1ZTEiLCJleHAiOjE2OTY5OTA1MjJ9.V_p9wX-rxULPvwIsuh4CFX-dosunJMiKHa5gCU9XGCg'}
2023-10-10 21:45:23,054|INFO | token validation successful
2023-10-10 21:45:23,054|INFO | ['/dev/sg6', '/dev/sg61']
2023-10-10 21:45:23,058|INFO | 10.168.101.99 - - [10/Oct/2023:21:45:23 -0400] "GET /storage/megaraid/controller/list?serial=USWSJ01219EZ0023 HTTP/1.1" 200 3 "<url-deleted-for-posting>10.168.101.129/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-10-10 21:45:23,077|INFO | ['/dev/sg6', '/dev/sg61']
2023-10-10 21:45:23,082|INFO | ['/dev/sg6', '/dev/sg61']
2023-10-10 21:45:23,136|INFO | 10.168.101.99 - - [10/Oct/2023:21:45:23 -0400] "GET /platform/health?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJwdWJsaWNfaWQiOiIxNTgyNGI4Ni00NTQyLTQxODgtOWVjMi1mYWI2ZmVjYTg1ZTEiLCJleHAiOjE2OTY5OTA1MjJ9.V_p9wX-rxULPvwIsuh4CFX-dosunJMiKHa5gCU9XGCg&serial=USWSJ01219EZ0023 HTTP/1.1" 200 924 "<url-deleted-for-posting>10.168.101.129/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-10-10 21:45:23,193|INFO | wddcs get_handles ['/dev/sg6', '/dev/sg61']
2023-10-10 21:45:23,324|ERROR| Exception on /dashboard/capacity [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 867, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 852, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 489, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/flask/views.py", line 109, in view
    return current_app.ensure_sync(self.dispatch_request)(**kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 604, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/usm/inbandmgmt/app/api/dashboard/dashboard.py", line 101, in get
    return self.capacity(serial,controller_id)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/usm/inbandmgmt/app/api/dashboard/dashboard.py", line 111, in capacity
    (populated_size, populated_slots) = HD.JBOF_size(serial)
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/usm/inbandmgmt/app/services/storage/hard_drive_info.py", line 55, in JBOF_size
    handles = WDDCS.get_handles(serial,1,True)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/usm/inbandmgmt/app/services/hal/wddcs_wrapper.py", line 557, in get_handles
    slot_map = (list(map(get_slot_map,output)))
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/usm/inbandmgmt/app/services/hal/wddcs_wrapper.py", line 447, in get_slot_map
    if items[dev_index].startswith("/dev/") or items[dev_index].startswith("PD"):
       ~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am looking at the code behind calls from the /python3.11/ folder and any .PY files and examine other bits of the code to determine how to trace down the source of the issue, but this morning it occurred to me that the errors are always Python related.

Here are the details of the packages that are involved in the stack:

**Python 3.11**

```
    Package            Version
------------------ ------------
aniso8601          9.0.1
blinker            1.6.3
certifi            2022.9.24
cffi               1.16.0
chardet            5.1.0
charset-normalizer 3.0.1
click              8.1.7
cryptography       41.0.4
dbus-python        1.3.2
distro             1.8.0
dnspython          2.4.2
Flask              3.0.0
Flask-Cors         4.0.0
Flask-RESTful      0.3.10
httplib2           0.20.4
idna               3.3
itsdangerous       2.1.2
Jinja2             3.1.2
json2html          1.3.0
lazr.restfulclient 0.14.5
lazr.uri           1.0.6
MarkupSafe         2.1.3
oauthlib           3.2.2
Paste              3.6.0
pip                23.0.1
pycparser          2.21
pycurl             7.45.2
PyGObject          3.42.2
PyJWT              2.8.0
pymongo            4.5.0
pyOpenSSL          23.2.0
pyparsing          3.0.9
PySimpleSOAP       1.16.2
python-apt         2.6.0
python-debian      0.1.49
python-debianbts   4.0.1
pytz               2023.3.post1
reportbug          12.0.0
requests           2.28.1
setuptools         66.1.1
six                1.16.0
urllib3            1.26.12
wadllib            1.3.6
waitress           2.1.2
Werkzeug           3.0.0
wheel              0.38.4
```

- **Western Digital Tools:**

```
Western Digital Resource Manager v 1.3 for Linux
wddcs/now 3.0.8.0 amd64
wdckit-raid/now 2.14.0.0
```

- **Also:**

```
sg3-utils-udev/stable 1.46-3 all
sg3-utils/stable,now 1.46-3 amd64
```

I figured that if I could manually make some calls in some way or otherwise trace the details of every action being taken, I might see more detail and make some headway on finding the root cause.

Perhaps someone here can see the issue more plainly than I?

Is there some way I can get more detail in the log?

Are there other logs I should examine or enable that could help?